# Digital LOGIC MICROELECTRONIC

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

Whenever I have "input" which it could be HIGH AND LOW for example the input VIN to the CMOS INVERTER then we assume that the iput is 0 or vdd ! what's confusing me who said that high can't be VDD-VT ? I mean why we are generally taking the high as VDD and not VDD-VT ?!
the same with low, we generally say that LOW is zero but it could be VT .. so why we are taking in analysis circuit whenever telling me that input is LOW then we say it's zero ?! why not saying it's VT?!

Comment: What is that "VT"? Have you looked at the datasheet of the inverter you're talking about? You are making assumptions that you are not telling us about.

Comment: You've been pointed to this before: Please write and format to the best of your abilities. This is terrible to read. You *can* do better. Do better. Downvoting due to lack of due diligence.

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Because often, the exact voltage isn't known.

When the input signal is LOW, you're right could be any value between 0V and some other maximum upper value. It is either defined in the component's datasheet defined value, e.g. 0.3V. Or, in case of TTL, bewwteen 0V and 0.8V. But the real signal can be 0.1V or 0.23V or 0.7854V.

We *say* it is zero or 0V, because we *mean* it is somewhere between 0V and this maximum upper value, because we don't know the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

It  depends on the information given in datasheets. It is not always necessary that VDD is the 'High'.  But most of the time it is because these conponents are made like this and using an extra voltage regulator is not a good idea to reduce the voltage that specifies 'High'.